# is there any way to fit video into single screen for all device and for all browser

Tags: html, css

i have video at banner and i want is that vedio should fit into  single screen for all device and for all browser the the probleis that its look smaller in height in chrome but looks larger in safari

```css
.banner{
    position: relative;
  }
  video {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div className="banner">
               <div className="spread-video">
                  <video playsInline muted autoPlay loop  src={BannerVideo1} type='video/mp4'/>
               </div>
               </div>
```

[image]

Comment: So if there is no place for your video to fit into device dimensions to be seen properly, how do you expect to fit it then?

Comment: Have you tried adding the width to video. `<video playsInline muted autoPlay loop  src={BannerVideo1} type='video/mp4' width='100%'/>`

Comment: yes i tryed width:100%

Comment: just see bottom of screen shot that black space i want to fill that in height in termof width its fine

Comment: don't see width see height

Comment: It should work with width: 100%; ... Try adding: `height: auto;` to the video

Comment: Its not clear what that screenshot is trying to show - it appears to be just a tiny part of the actual screen? Please show us the full screen so we can understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Media Queries.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

```
.spread-video{
        @media(max-width: 768px) {
        /*Styles to be executed when screen is narrower than 768px*/
        }
    }
```

Media queries are used for responsive web development, and are highly customizable. The above is just an example of using the `max-width` style property to deterime which styles need to be applied. You can use multiple media queries in one class to cover what needs to be covered.

Comment: just see bottom of screen shot that black space i want to fill that in height in termof width its fine